# How to stop link move on hover

Tags: css

I have a problem some of my links keep moving a couple of pixel on hover does anyone know a fix for this.

Currently me code is like this

```
<a class="read-more-link" href="/what-to-do-now/week49/flowers-checklist/">See all Flowers jobs</a>
```

the css

```
    a:hover{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
a{
    color: #172D02;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.checklist .read-more-link:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.checklist .read-more-link {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    background: url("/images/double_arrow.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you have `border-bottom` set on `hover`.

Therefore this is adding a `1px` border underneath your link when it is hovered over. This can affect the position of other relative elements.

Change this to `text-decoration:underline;` or add a hidden `border-bottom` to the standard style:

```
a {
border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be set because the border color is different to the text link

Comment: In this case, add `border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;` to your `a` style

Answer (score 0):

write

```
  a:hover{
      text-decoration:underline;
    }

in place of

    a:hover{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

and remove this  there is no need of it

```
.checklist a, .checklist a:visited {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add one empty container like below, on top:

```
<div class="container" style="height:5px"></div>
```